Refer to local pip packages in a Conda environment used by Snakemake
I am trying to use Conda environments with Snakemake to ensure that workflows run with a reproducible software environment. However, some libraries need to be installed from the directory in which the Snakefile sits, rather than from a Conda channel or PyPI.
For example, outside of Snakemake I would use an environment.yml something like:
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.11.8=hb885b13_0
  - pip:
    - ./libs/mylib1
    - ./libs/mylib2

This fails when using snakemake --use-conda, since Snakemake changes directory so that the relative path is no longer correct.
On my machine I can work around this problem by instead using ../../libs/mylib1, etc., but I fear that may not be portable if people use the --conda-prefix option to relocate where their Conda packages are created.
Is there a better way to specify this?

You could include those as requirements for your snakemake environment. So your user clones your repo, which as a env.yaml that specifies snakemake as well as your local packages. Then when they run snakemake in that env, those packages are available.

That's an option, but at that point I'm completely giving up on Snakemake's Conda integration where it can automatically instantiate minimal environments for each workflow step.

That’s true, but unless your packages are large I would assume the overhead would be minimal. You could also publish the packages to pypi.

Or if not PyPI, either build them to Conda packages locally and host them on a user channel on Anaconda Cloud (this is what I do), or, if ready for reuse, then write recipes for them in Bioconda (assuming Snakemake implies bioinfo, which may not be true).

Not bioinformatics, no. I'm trying to package a complete workflow on Zenodo with a persistent identifier and a relative guarantee of long-term stability, with any non-standard dependencies baked in rather than relying on a service like Anaconda Cloud that could be withdrawn or have its terms changed. Standard dependencies like Numpy and Matplotlib would be easy to find, but packages that only have one or two users less so.
